# logger: unrecognized option '--rfc3164' message is shown after execute every command

Tags: logging, ubuntu-14.04, rsyslog

I'm using ubuntu14.04 server.

working with apache, php, nodejs and mysql 
there is nothing special service.

but weird log is show up from oneday.

shown below

```
logger: unrecognized option '--rfc3164'

Usage:
 logger [options] [message]


Options:

 -d, --udp             use UDP (TCP is default)
 -i, --id              log the process ID too
 -f, --file <file>     log the contents of this file
 -h, --help            display this help text and exit
 -n, --server <name>   write to this remote syslog server
 -P, --port <number>   use this UDP port
 -p, --priority <prio> mark given message with this priority
 -s, --stderr          output message to standard error as well
 -t, --tag <tag>       mark every line with this tag
 -u, --socket <socket> write to this Unix socket
 -V, --version         output version information and exit
```

It's shown after every command is executed.

I tried kill each of services. but it not modified.
and find all file use `logger`. I think it's involved in `rsyslogd` but I can't figure it out how to remove it or modify it.

Anyone who knows how to fix that problem?

Comment: What command do you mean? `logger` is not related (directly) to `rsyslogd`. Your `logger` version does not support the `--rfc3164` option but for some reason you are using that option.